# how can I get rid off this error and why am I not getting on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm making a json request using jquery from here http://quotes.rest/qod.json and I keep getting this error in the logs. Does this matter, and how can I get rid of it? and finally why I"m not displaying anything on the page. I can see the quote on the logs. why not on the page? what am I missing? Thanks

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: json is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (VM1741 pen.js:9)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (VM1796 jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (VM1796 jquery.min.js:3)
```

this is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  /*getting random quote on button click*/
  $('#getMessage').on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("https://quotes.rest/qod.json", function(json) {      
      console.log(json.contents.quotes[0])
      var quoteArr = json.contents.quotes[0];
      console.log(quoteArr.quote)
      console.log(quoteArr.author)
});
    $("#quote-content").html(quoteArr.quote);
    $("#quote-author").html(quoteArr.author);
  });  
});
```

Comment: Your two lines towards the bottom (`$(..).html`) should be within the `$.getJSON` callback function. That's probably why you're not seeing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working fine :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  /*getting random quote on button click*/
  $('#getMessage').on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("https://quotes.rest/qod.json", function(json) {      
        console.log(json.contents.quotes[0])
        var quoteArr = json.contents.quotes[0];
        console.log(quoteArr.quote)
        console.log(quoteArr.author)

        $("#quote-content").html(quoteArr.quote);
        $("#quote-author").html(quoteArr.author);
    });
  });  
});
```

The only issue is with the position of this code block :

```
$("#quote-content").html(quoteArr.quote);
$("#quote-author").html(quoteArr.author);
```

Comment: thanks, why I keep getting the same quote over and over?

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get your error in my tryout. I have done minor modifications to the code though

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  /*getting random quote on button click*/
  $('#getMessage').on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("https://quotes.rest/qod.json", function(json) {      
          console.log(json.contents.quotes[0])
          var quoteArr = json.contents.quotes[0];
          console.log(quoteArr.quote)
          console.log(quoteArr.author)
          $("#quote-content").html(quoteArr.quote);
          $("#quote-author").html(quoteArr.author);
    });
  });  
});
```

I hope this helps.
I used jquery 1.9.1 .
[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ohrzxkLe/)